# Magento - How to enable cancel button for a processing order (invoice created)

Tags: magento, admin, orders

I have some orders in Processing state. I know Magento do not allow to cancel invoiced orders, just create a credit memo, but I need to change it. I need to do something to undo the creation of the invoice and return it to "pending", or just cancel it.

Comment: have you find any clue or answer ? right now i am facing same issue

Comment: no solution. i just put the order in Holding

Comment: Samey issue here, can we change the  order status from DB to solve the issue...?

Answer (score 5):

Any invoiced orders in Magento cannot be **canceled**, but they can be **closed**.

You need to issue a **credit memo**, which is refund in Magento.

Answer (score 1):

As per my view you can do this by database.

Follow the below steps :

```
1. Find the order in sales flat order(sales_flat_order table) by order id.
2. Find the order item in sales flat order item(sales_flat_order_item table) by order id.
3. For enable cancel button you have to change below columns value from 1 to 0 for all order items.

//for invoice order.
A] qty_invoiced : 0

//for shipped order.
B] qty_shipped : 0

This change will enable "Cancel Button" in admin sales view page.

4. Now you can change the order status from sales_flat_order table or cancel order.
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone still looking for it..
Module from mgt-commerce.com called Delete Orders allows you to delete any orders in admin. However when you delete an order it doesn't change qty in stock. [Delete Orders mgm](http://www.mgt-commerce.com/magento-delete-orders.html)

Answer (score -2):

You can't cancel orders in Magento that have invoices. You also can't 'undo' an invoice. With that said, I've discovered a plugin that might be able to help with canceling orders (these should primarily be used in the testing phase of your website and not when its live to avoid any complications):

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/asperience-deleteorders.html

Comment: He asked for canceling an order..not for deletion